# GKE cluster egress setup

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running `GKE` cluster with single node. I have set up ingress for managing & forwarding rules inside `Kubernetes` cluster.

however by default pod use `instance (Node) IP` for external connection. I have not set up `NAT gateway` here. I have shared node external IP with the third party but changed IP from ephemeral to static to keep it.

What is the best way possible now to manage a single IP for `egress` even if we do auto-scaling from single node to multi-node but egress IP will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The default behaviour for GKE](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#google-compute-engine-gce) when pods send traffic outside of the cluster, SNAT occurs and the node IP is used to replace the pod IP. The destination will only see the node IP. If you have more than 1 node, you will end up with more than 1 source IP.

Your best option to ensure you have a single IP for egress traffic is to use [Cloud NAT with GKE](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example)

Comment: no it will have to be a private cluster. If you don't want to recreate your cluster, you will need to use a unmanaged, manually created NAT gateway instead

Comment: do you mean unmanaged NAT gateway by setting up sperate one VM and direct traffic from it ?

Comment: exactly, something like [this](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google/1.2.2/examples/gke-nat-gateway)

Answer (score 1):

Since all of my instance in public subnet managed GKE NAT gateway will not work.i have used this for my public GKE cluster.

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google/1.2.2/examples/gke-nat-gateway